# How to download files using AppMobi XDK. Can't get it to work

Tags: php, javascript, html, appmobi

Does anyone know of a way to download a file in appMobi? I have tried force downloading and just opening the file I wish to download, both times, nothing happens.

Comment: If no one knows how to do this, then is there a way to open a browser window with a preset url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to cache. Documentation [here](http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/cache.html?x=7205#cache.addToMediaCacheExt).